# Problem to use an address within a contract. Error: invalid address

Tags: addresses

I have a private blockchain.

I am creating a contract and then I am calling a function that returns the main account. I have the error calling this function.

This is the contract creation code:

```
var browser_untitled1_sol_mytokenContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"GetMain","outputs":[{"name":"resultMain","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"GetBalance","outputs":[{"name":"result","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);
var browser_untitled1_sol_mytoken = browser_untitled1_sol_mytokenContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

I call the function `browser_untitled1_sol_mytoken.GetMain();` to get the main address and get the error:

```
Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3879:15
    at web3.js:3705:20
    at web3.js:4948:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4947:12
    at web3.js:4973:18
    at web3.js:4998:23
    at web3.js:4061:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4147:16
```

Comment: have you got the message Contract mined! address:.........? when you ve deployed your contract

Comment: @Badr Bellaj   >Yes I have the confirmation :                                           >`loadScript("Contrato4.js")
null [object Object]
true
> null [object Object]
Contract mined! address: 0x28affe3b07d6448ae6dbf232ec56f070bf91d036 transactionHash: 0x96a918c45d7292b02b9fbd50d0d5ee527ff7efa7f2c87d61aa8dd179df12f19c`

Answer (score 0):

*I believe*, this line is in error:

```
 }, function (e, contract){
```

You don't get the contract address from `contract.new()`. You get the transaction hash. Then, as Badr says, you have to wait for the transaction to be mined.

I've had good luck with this library: https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6

You just include the code in your JS and then when you send transactions, you follow up with (uses promises which are consistent with Truffle):

```
.then(function (txnHash) {
  return web3.eth.getTransactionReceiptMined(txnHash);
})
.then
```

It's readable and reliable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I undrestand your point, but after I had the confirmation that it was mined. I can run   `>browser_untitled1_sol_mytoken.address
"0x1e9e7465e394ae1b39344eaf81aea9393d4a690e"`
I can also get the contract details by running: `> browser_untitled1_sol_mytoken

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, the difference is you are waiting for the transaction to be mined while the script is not waiting. It's trying to txnHash.address which is undefined.

Comment: Finally I found the issue. I had to add `constant` within the function to get that working.  `>browser_untitled1_sol_mytoken.GetBalance();
21000000`

Comment: Can someone explain what `constant` does within the function declaration?  `>function GetBalance()constant returns(uint256 result) {
     result=balance;
     return result;
 }`

Comment: Constant is read-only operation. it runs locally. It doesn't update the chain and it can't make a state change no matter what the function says. It returns return values instead of a transaction hash because the result is available without waiting for the network to decide what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the default account and then execute:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

Hope this helps...!